# Smart pointer or Regular pointer for vector of vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am wondering if any problems would occur if i use smart pointer for vector of vector.Im making a container object that will hold derived objects (including other containers), i want to use smart pointers for self deletion and wanted to use unique_ptr for single ownership, but can not use it in this case.

each container has a size, so the last container cannot not contain the first, which would prevent one of the problems ive read on for shared_pt.

```
class Base{...}

class Item:public Base{...}

class Container : public Base{
    //int size;
    vector<shared_ptr<Base>>vec;
public:
     template <typename D>
     void AddItem(const D& thing) {
     vec.push_back(make_shared<D>(thing));
     }
};

Container bag;
Item thing;
Container bag2;

bag2.AddItem<Item>(thing);

bag.AddItem<Container>(bag2);
```

//**_________________________**

related, why doesn't this work

```
class Container :public Base{
vector<Base*>slot;
public:
~Container(){}

void Add(Base* thing){ slot.push_back(thing); }

void Delte_All()
{
    for(int i=0;i<slot.size();++i)
    {
        delete slot[i];
        cout << "Object " << i << " deleted" <<endl;
    }
    slot.clear();
}

};

int main()
{
Container bag;
Container bag2;
Base* thing=&bag2;

bag.Add(thing);

bag.Delte_All();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>>`

Answer (score 1):

- No problem with smart pointers(e.g., `shared_ptr`) on your first case.
  FYI, When you call `make_shared<Item>(thing)`, `thing` is copied on the heap.
- On your second case(with raw pointers),
  `bag2` is an object on the stack,
  and you cannot delete any object allocated on the stack. (*)